# Does azure support things like mongodb and redis?

Tags: mongodb, azure, memcached, redis

Can you use mongodb and redis/memcached with azure?

I'm guessing no but just want to make sure.

It turns out they do support things other than .net, are they using linux servers then?

Comment: Iit looks like there is a windows port of redis [here](https://github.com/dmajkic/redis) which should work on azure. Still, redis is probably something you want to run on a unix system.

Comment: I've run Redis without trouble.

Comment: @smarx How did you get Redis up and running on Azure?

Comment: I have added a separate question regarding Redis and Azure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140669/howto-get-redis-running-on-azure#comment13003794_10140669

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can very easily run mongodb in Windows Azure. I presented this at MongoSV - video [here](http://www.10gen.com/video/mongosv2010/azure).

***EDIT***: In December 2011, 10gen published their official MongoDB+Azure code on [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-azure). This contains a project for replica-sets, as well as a demo ASP.NET MVC application (taken from the Windows Azure Platform Training Kit) that uses a replica set for its storage.

Standalone servers are straightforward, except you have to deal with scale-out: you can't have multiple instances of a standalone server simultaneously, so you'll need to plan for this: take all but one out of the load balancer, or only launch mongod if you can acquire the Cloud Drive lock.

Replicasets are doable, as I demonstrated at MongoSV. However, I didn't cover the intricacies of graceful shutdown of a replicaset to ensure zero data loss.

You can run memcached as well - see David Aiken's [post](http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/01/11/windows-azure-memcached-plugin/) about this. Note: Now that the AppFabric Cache service is live, you should look into the pros/cons of using that over memcached. Cost-wise, AppFabric Cache should run much less, as you don't have to pay for role instances to host your cache. More info about AppFabric Cache [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazureappfabric/archive/2011/04/10/windows-azure-appfabric-caching-availability-announced.aspx).

Comment: so MS is running linux boxes also then?

Comment: No linux boxes - Windows Server 2008 SP2 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Might wanna split your question into two questions then. I know about running MongoDB, not redis, hence no mention of redis in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You now also have the option of [running Redis in Windows Azure on Linux virtual machines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2012/06/08/running-redis-on-a-centos-linux-vm-in-windows-azure.aspx) ! In the case of Redis, this would allow you to use the "official" build instead of the "unsupported" Windows build ... For MongoDB, both choices seem equally valid (running on Linux  virtual machines, "plain" Windows virtual machines, or using 10gen's package to run on "managed" VMs (Cloud Services).

Answer (score 1):

FYI, there's now a Redis installer for Windows Azure available from MS Open Tech (my team). Here's a tutorial on how to use it: http://ossonazure.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/how-to-deploy-redis-to-windows-azure-using-the-command-line-tool

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE] Azure now supports MongoDB and Redis.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/22/announcing-new-mongodb-instances-on-microsoft-azure/
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure Store you can now select Redis Cloud as an add-on.

Heres the Azure store description:

"Redis Cloud is a fully-managed cloud service for hosting and running Redis in a highly-available and scalable manner, with predictable and stable top performance. Tell us how much memory you need and get started instantly with your new Redis database."
PUBLISHED DATE 3/31/2014

You can access the store by selecting the "New" button in the Azure portal then "Store". I have yet to use it but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Azure now has a first-party Redis service, currently in preview:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/