# node.js application deployment in Windows Azure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, redis, socket.io

I have built my application using node.js, mongodb, redis, express, socket.io and planning to deploy it in azure. I have seen that azure has a good support for node.js and it also supports mongo. But I am not very sure if it supports redis as well. redis seems to be production ready in unix/linux, but not yet ready for windows, though it works there.

So can we take a linux VM in azure and install redis there ? is it possible ?

Can I take 1 VM for node, 1 for mongo and 1 for redis ?

If I have a clustered node, will there be any problem with socket.io ? Is Nginx required ?

Please treat this as a first timer's question for deploying node.js application in Azure.

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766815/does-azure-support-things-like-mongodb-and-redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deploy Linux VMs into Windows Azure...yet.  This may change with the next Azure SDK.

Comment: Thanks. looks like cloudfoundry is my best bet.

Comment: This is no longer the case.  You can deploy Linux VM's to Azure now.   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/

Answer (score 2):

You can now install Linux VM on Azure and you can allocate VMs as much as you want.

But, Windows Azure also supports now Node.js as a Website.
Last, you can use mongo as a service like [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/) and Redis as a service like [Redislabs](http://redislabs.com/).

But, Socket.io is an issue, since [Windows Azure LB](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balance-virtual-machines/) supports only Round-Robin, which means you might need to set Nginx in front of the app.