# How to get Redis running on Azure?

Tags: azure, redis

I have seen several references to people running Redis on Azure, but no implementation or any sort of 'howto' on it. Has anyone seen such an example?

Comment: Links to these references please?

Comment: See the comments on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766815/does-azure-support-things-like-mongodb-and-redis

Comment: And now of course Microsoft is running Redis as a service in Azure: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/cache/#redis

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. Download Redis for Windows - see the section 'Redis Service builds for Windows' on https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis.  I ended up using the win64 version from dmajkic https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads
2. Create an Azure worker role, delete the default class (you don't need c# code at all).  Add the file redis-server.exe from the downloaded redis source (the exe can be found in redis/src).
3. In the service definition file add the following config

   ```
   <WorkerRole name="my.Worker" vmsize="Small">
     <Runtime executionContext="limited">
       <EntryPoint>
         <ProgramEntryPoint commandLine="redis-server.exe" setReadyOnProcessStart="true" />
       </EntryPoint>
     </Runtime>
     <Imports>
       <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
       <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
       <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
     </Imports>
     <Endpoints>
       <InternalEndpoint name="Redis" protocol="tcp" port="6379" />
     </Endpoints>
   </WorkerRole>
   ```
4. You can refer to the redis server from your web role using the following

   ```
   var ipEndpoint = RoleEnvironment.Roles["my.Worker"].Instances[0].InstanceEndpoints["Redis"].IPEndpoint;
   host = string.Format("{0}:{1}", ipEndpoint.Address, ipEndpoint.Port);
   ```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 14):

FYI, the above-mentioned Redis on Windows project from MS Open Tech now has an Azure installer available, which makes it easy to get Redis up and running on a PaaS worker role. Here's a detailed tutorial: http://ossonazure.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/how-to-deploy-redis-to-windows-azure-using-the-command-line-tool (Full disclosure: I'm on the MS Open Tech team.)

Comment: It would be nice to have a small GUI (WPF application) for `RedisInstWA.exe` to make it more accessible to people to run Redis on Azure. I have used the linux virtual machine method because of my limited knowledge about the azure config files. But still curious what performs better, PaaS worker role or centOs virtual machine.

Comment: Hi JP, just saw your comment. Great idea about a GUI front end -- would you be willing to log it as a request on the Guthub repo? (https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues) I'll follow up to try to make it happen. As for perf comparisons between PaaS and IaaS, we'll be looking into that but don't have results yet.

Comment: Sure, will do! https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues/50 p.s. i didn't got it to work with the tutorial so I ended up using a virtual linux machine with this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2012/06/08/running-redis-on-a-centos-linux-vm-in-windows-azure.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is  [MS Open Tech: Redis on Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/04/26/here-s-to-the-first-release-from-ms-open-tech-redis-on-windows.aspx) project.
Redis on Windows is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Redis) 
 (https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis) however still not labelled as ready for production yet.

Another post is an example of application using Redis:"[SignalR with Redis Running on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-with-Redis-Running-on-a-Windows-Azure-Virtual-Machine)"