# pub\sub between redis cache and in-memory cache

Tags: c#, azure, redis, azure-caching, booksleeve

In my webpage I've created two kinds of cache:

- in memory cache, for every process.
- out-of-process cache. I used Redis (specifically Booksleeve).

Now that I have those 2 built, I would like to form a communication between them. I would like that every time the Redis cache is updated with new record, it'll signal (publish?) the in memory caches, and "send" them the new record. On the other side, the in-memory caches probably need to be "listening" to the redis cache (subscribe?), my question is how does it work, exactly? and how can I do that in C#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16618032/23354

Comment: More Info : same user for the same question. Marc's answer is great and was accepted. I don't understand why you ask the same thing again.

Comment: It was before I've noticed his answer @Cybermaxs-Betclic . Sorry