# Is redis on azure durable across deployments?

Tags: azure, redis

I'm evaluating deploying Redis on windows azure to support an application I'm building.  I've found a couple of different methods for deployment.

1. The first is to create a worker-role for redis-server.exe, and set the `ProgramEntryPoint` in the csdef file - [Howto get Redis running on Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140669/howto-get-redis-running-on-azure)
2. The other is to use the tool RedisInstWA by [following these instructions](http://ossonazure.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/how-to-deploy-redis-to-windows-azure-using-the-command-line-tool)

If I use option 1, then Redis' db file will be overwritten on each deployment.

I see in the documentation that RedisInstWA uses an Azure Storage Account, is that used to store the database files, for staging components for deployment, something else?  Is there a way to maintain the redis dbs across deployments?  Or is there a way to grab a copy of the db file, so it can be deployed along with the server to ensure data isn't lost on subsequent deployments (should they be necessary).

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just host it on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine which is both persistent and durable.

Comment: yeah...  it's a bit more expensive, and then i have to get involved in server maintenance.  but that may be the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Jason, you should be able to just re-run RedisInstWA to re-deploy the executable as needed, and your data will remain on the Azure storage account you've set up. Have you tried it?

Comment: I haven't tried it, I haven't set up my non-emulated azure account yet.